# How do I reapply knockout js bindings to a file input element after initializing jQuery fileupload?

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-file-upload

I've got a viewModel set up that gets the width and height from text inputs. I want to pass that width and height to the data-width and data-height attributes on the file input.

I'm using [jQuery.fileupload.js](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to handle the file upload process. The issue I'm seeing is that after you've added a file to the file input, the bindings to the data attributes no longer update when the text inputs are changed.

html

```
<input id="file" type="file" data-bind="attr:{'data-height': height, 'data-width': width}" /><br />
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: width" /><br />
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: height" />
```

scripts

```
var ViewModel = function(width, height) {
  this.width = ko.observable(width);
  this.height = ko.observable(height);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(300, 300));

var $file = $('#file');
$file.fileupload({
    add: function(){
    ko.cleanNode($file[0]);
    ko.applyBindings(ViewModel, $file[0]);
  },
  change: function(e, data) {
    ko.cleanNode($file[0]);
    ko.applyBindings(ViewModel, $file[0]);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jrwdev/1n9ye60z/3/

How can I ensure that the bindings stay or are at least re-bound to the file input when the input element gets updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see this behaviour because of the [**`replaceFileInput`**](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js#L105) option of  `jQuery.fileupload.js`:

> By default, the file input field is replaced with a clone after each
>   input field change event.
>   This is required for iframe transport queues
>   and allows change events to be fired for the same file selection, but
>   can be disabled by setting the following option to false:
>   replaceFileInput: true

Because of this, any Knockout bindings don't get applied (anymore) on this clone.

The example below has an additional `title` binding bound to the viewmodel's `width` property on the upload button (being its tooltip) to show that this doesn't only affect bound `data-`attributes.

Notice that with `replaceFileInput` set to `false`, the `title` still updates after having chosen a file.

Be aware that you can only apply this in case your application doesn't need iframe transport queues.

```js
var ViewModel = function(width, height) {
    this.width = ko.observable(width);
    this.height = ko.observable(height);
};

var $file = $('#file');
$file.fileupload({
    replaceFileInput: false
});

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(300, 300));
```

```html
<script src="https://dev4.promotionpod.com/static/scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dev4.promotionpod.com/static/internal/uploader/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="https://dev4.promotionpod.com/static/internal/uploader/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="https://dev4.promotionpod.com/static/internal/uploader/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input id="file" type="file" data-bind="attr:{'data-height': height, 'data-width': width, title: width}" /><br />
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: width" /><br />
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: height" />
```